# Confusion regarding a printf statement

Tags: c, printf

So I was running this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y)
{
return printf("%*c%*c",x ,' ',y,' ');

}
int main()
{
printf("Sum = %d", add(3,4));
return 0;
}
```

And can't seem to understand how does the following statement works

```
return printf("%*c%*c",x ,' ',y,' ');
```

So I tried writing a simple code

```
int x=3;
printf("%*c",x);
```

and I got a weird special character (some spaces before it) as output

```
printf("%*c",x,' ');
```

I am getting no output. I have no idea what is happening? Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
int x=3;
printf("%*c",x,'a');
```

makes use of the minimum character width that can be set for each input parameter to `printf`.

What the above does is print out the `a` character, but specifies that the minimum width will be `x` characters - so the output will be the `a` character preceded by 2 spaces.

The `*` specifier tells `printf` that the width of the part of the output string formed from this input parameter will be `x` characters minimum width where `x` must be passed as additional argument **prior** to the variable that is to be printed. The extra width (if required) is formed from blank spaces output **before** the variable to be printed. In this case the width is 3 and so the output string is (excluding the quotes which are just there to illustrate the spaces)

```
"  a"
```

With your code here

```
printf("%*c",x);
```

you have passed the length value, but forgotten to actually pass the variable that you want printed.

So this code

```
return printf("%*c%*c",x ,' ',y,' ');
```

is basically saying to print the space character but with a minimum width of `x` characters (with your code x = 3), then print the space character with a minimum of `y` characters (in your code y = 4).

The result is that you are printing out 7 blank space characters. This length is the return value of `printf` (and hence your `add` function) which is confirmed by the output of

```
Sum = 7
```

from the `printf` inside `main()`.

If you change your code to

```
return printf("%*c%*c",x ,'a',y,'b');
```

you would see the string (obviously excluding the quotes)

```
"  a    b"
```

printed which would make what is happening more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It's crystal clear now

Answer (score 2):

Try to print that in the correct way. `%d` is for printing integer, `%c` is for printing char.

In your code:

```
int x=3;
printf("%*c",x);
```

The `x` is how much spaces the char will get, you write 3. But you didn't put the char you want to print, so it print garbage.

When you write:

```
printf("%*c",x,' ');
```

You printing space `' '` char inside 3 chars space.
Same thing when you do
`printf("%*c",x, ' ',y,' ');` - just 7 blank spaces. The result is correct because `printf` returns how many characters it writes.

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for extra `printf` formats.