# What is %*c%*c in `printf`?

Tags: c, printf

When i use printf in `%*c%*c` in `printf`,  it requires 4 values and also prints the sum of 4 and 5. I could not find a valid reason for this.

When researching, I found that `%*c` denotes the width. But what is width and how come the sum is derived for below example ?

```
printf("%*c%*c", 4, ' ', 5, ' ');
```

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/XiQcdk)

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return printf("%*c%*c",x,' ', y,' ');
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",add(4,5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your entire sample code to your post, as well as the output – in this case it is important for the answer!

Comment: You might want to read [a `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: Oh and all that the `printf` call you show us does is print 9 spaces.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606791/confusion-regarding-a-printf-statement/30607107#30607107

Comment: Ah, now with the edit it's much clearer, and the answer will be clear if you read the reference I linked to before, especially what `printf` *returns*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf("%*c%*c", 4, ' ', 5, ' ');` prints a space in a field of size 4 followed by a space in a field of size 5. So a total of 9 chars.

In your posted code, the function returns the result of `printf` which gives the number of printed chars, so 9. In main you then print this number 9.

Answer (score 8):

`printf` returns the number of characters printed.

`printf("%*c", N, C);` prints `N-1` blanks followed by the character C.

More generally, `printf` prints `N - length_of_text` blanks (if that number is `> 0`, zero blanks otherwise) followed by the text. The same applies to numbers as well.

therefore

```
return printf("%*c%*c", x, ' ', y, ' ');
```

prints a space prefixed with `x` minus length_of_space other spaces (`x-1`), then does the same for `y`. That makes `4+5` spaces in your case. Then `printf` returns the total number of characters printed, 9.

```
printf("%d",add(4,5));
```

This `printf` prints the integer returned by the `add()` function, 9.

By default, `printf` is right-aligned (blanks before text). To make it *left*-aligned, either

- give a negative `N`, or
- add a `-` before the `*`, e.g. `%-*s`, or
- the static version works as well, e.g. `%-12s`, `%-6d`

Comment: No, `printf("%*c",N,C)` prints the char C in a field of size N.

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is as expected. According to the [manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

> **format**
>   (optional) . followed by integer number or *, or neither that specifies precision of the conversion. **In the case when * is used, the precision is specified by an additional argument of type int.** If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor * is used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact effects of precision.
>
> **Return value**
>   1-2) Number of characters written if successful or negative value if an error occurred.

So in your case:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return printf("%*c%*c",x,' ', y,' ');
    //              ^ x is for the first *, y for the second *
}
```

As a result, the `x + y` number of space(including the precision) written, which is the return value.